# How can I add an AuthorizeAttribute to all controllers in a given assembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

In WebApi I know I can use the following code to ensure all my controllers use a specific authorize attribute:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new MyCustomAuthorizeAttribute());
```

However, my API project is being implemented in a sub-path under an existing web app which is already running its own API under a separate path. I therefore need a version of the above which only works with the controllers in my WebApi assembly. Anyone know the best way to do this?

Comment: Interesting scenario. You might have to mark your WebApi assembly controllers directly. Do they share a base class? If so, just mark the base class.

Comment: Could you not subclass the `MyCustomAuthorizeAttribute` such that it checked for the path before attempting authorization?

Comment: Thanks guys, both valid suggestions and both applicable in my scenario.

Comment: I think @diskjunky answers my specific question more directly...

Comment: ...but I think I prefer @juan's idea because I'm more decoupled from that other API. Still curious if there might be other solutions.

Comment: Well, when you add a filter like you have in your code sample, you are not adding it to the controllers. You are adding a GLOBAL filter that applies to all requests. What you are asking now is to go more granular, so you can't use any global strategy, unless you do things like path, assembly or type checking in the attribute which is not very efficient and error-prone.

Comment: When you say a sub-path, do you mean your project is published into a sub-application under a site in IIS? If this is the case, then I think they are already separated. You can certainly run these sub-applications in their own app pools for example.

Comment: Hi @craig-h, no it's all one application where the WebApi is a separate project loaded as a dependency of the main Web project and set up to run under a specific base route.